# How to inject D3 & D3plus together in Angular webapp?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, d3.js, d3plus

I am trying to include d3Plus sample code (http://d3plus.org/examples/basic/32517cfde67270c99092/) in my  webapp based on angular.

**The skeleton code**:

```
angular.module('UI', ['UI.controllers', 'UI.directives']);
angular.module('d3Plus', ['d3']);
angular.module('d3', []);
angular.module('UI.controllers', []);
angular.module('UI.directives', ['d3Plus']);

angular.module('d3').factory('d3',[function(){ 
    var d3;    
    d3=minimized/code/of/d3.js
    return d3;
}]) ;

angular.module('d3Plus').factory('d3Plus',['d3', function(){ 
    var d3Plus;    
    d3Plus=minimized/code/of/d3Plus.js
    return d3Plus;
}]) ;


angular.module('UI.directives').directive('d3Bars', ['d3', function(d3) {....}])
angular.module('UI.directives').directive('d3plusMap', ['d3Plus', function(d3) {....}])
```

**Error**:
When I try custom-tag  (directive created using d3Plus), I get following error in my console:
`ReferenceError: d3 is not defined` in angular.js line: 11496

Any help?

**Edit 1**: The d3 based tag - d3-bars works fine.

Answer (score 4):

How you can inject d3.js as a dependency in an angular.js  is described in [this ng-newsletter](http://www.ng-newsletter.com/posts/d3-on-angular.html):

```
angular.module('d3', [])
 .factory('d3Service', ['$document', '$q', '$rootScope',
   function($document, $q, $rootScope) {
    var d = $q.defer();
    function onScriptLoad() {
     // Load client in the browser
     $rootScope.$apply(function() { d.resolve(window.d3); });
    }
    // Create a script tag with d3 as the source
    // and call our onScriptLoad callback when it
    // has been loaded
    var scriptTag = $document[0].createElement('script');
    scriptTag.type = 'text/javascript'; 
    scriptTag.async = true;
    scriptTag.src = 'http://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js';
    scriptTag.onreadystatechange = function () {
      if (this.readyState == 'complete') onScriptLoad();
    }
    scriptTag.onload = onScriptLoad;

    var s = $document[0].getElementsByTagName('body')[0];
    s.appendChild(scriptTag);

    return {
      d3: function() { return d.promise; }
    };
  }]);
```

The same thing can be applied to any other JS-library. For d3plus, my working module/factory looks like this:

```
angular.module('d3plus', [])
  .factory('d3plusService', ['$document', '$window', '$q', '$rootScope',
  function ($document, $window, $q, $rootScope) {
  var d = $q.defer(),
    d3plusService = {
      d3plus: function () {
        return d.promise;
      }
    };

  function onScriptLoad() {
    // Load client in the browser
    $rootScope.$apply(function () {
      d.resolve($window.d3plus);
    });
  }
  var scriptTag = $document[0].createElement('script');
  scriptTag.type = 'text/javascript';
  scriptTag.async = true;
  scriptTag.src = 'path/to/d3plus.min.js';
  scriptTag.onreadystatechange = function () {
    if (this.readyState == 'complete') onScriptLoad();
  };
  scriptTag.onload = onScriptLoad;

  var s = $document[0].getElementsByTagName('body')[0];
  s.appendChild(scriptTag);

  return d3plusService;
}]);
```

Be sure to include the promise functions in your d3/d3plus directives like so:

```
app.directive('myD3Directive', ['d3Service', 'd3plusService',
function(d3service, d3plusService) {
    return {
      restrict: 'E',
      link: function(scope, elem, attrs) {

         d3service.d3().then(function (d3) {

           d3plusService.d3plus().then(function (d3plus) {

           // your code

           }
         }
      }
   }
}
]);
```

Answer (score -2):

I don't think that you pass in the `d3` as a dependency. Instead you reference it directly from your js source include (i.e. `<script src="http://d3js.org/d3.v2.js"></script>`)

You can find a [working example here on github](https://github.com/haroldcampbell/d3_angular_example_1).

Additional examples with source code can be found here: [D3.js Visualization Library with AngularJS](http://briantford.com/blog/angular-d3), [Angular.js Directives for nvd3.js, d3.js charts](https://github.com/cmaurer/angularjs-nvd3-directives).

If you prefer youtube videos: [AngularJS & D3: Directives for Visualizations](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aqHBLS_6gF8)

-harold